# Directive cannot bound for component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

**Update:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/kbz5uimNZ6vKTiT9QB6a?p=preview is created for testing.

I have the following directive `egFiles` to handle the status of `<input type="file" id="newFile" eg-files="model.files" has-file="model.hasFile" />` for file uploading.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').directive('egFiles', egFiles);

    function egFiles() {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                files: '=egFiles',
                hasFiles: '='
            }
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (element[0].files) {
                        scope.files.length = 0; // Breakpoint not hit here
                        angular.forEach(element[0].files, function (f) {
                            scope.files.push(f);
                        });
                        scope.hasFiles = true;
                    }
                });
            });

            if (element[0].form) {
                angular.element(element[0].form)
                        .bind('reset', function () {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.files.length = 0;
                                scope.hasFiles = false;
                            });
                        });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

The following the Anguar 1.5 component to consume the directive.

```
(function (undefined) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
    .component('doc', {
        template: '...
<input type="file" id="newFile" eg-files="model.files" has-file="model.hasFile" />
     ....',
        bindings: {
            id: '<',
            "$router": '<'
        },
        controllerAs: 'model',
        controller: [controller]
    });

    function controller() {
        var model = this;

        model.$routerOnActivate = function (next, previous) {
            model.id = next.params.id;
        }

        model.hasFile = false;
        model.uploading = false;
    }
})();
```

I set the break point in the function bound to `change` in directive egFiles. However the break point is never hit when I select a file by click the button?

Comment: Your Plunker is missing the `ng-app` attribute. It then tries to set the length on `undefined` as you have not defined `model.files` anywhere. Also, you seem to have a typo around `hasFiles` vs `hasFile`.

Comment: Here it is working as expected ~ https://plnkr.co/edit/YvU2gLakWnvBKp9GC3ED?p=preview

Comment: Its working fine for me . By breakpoint you meant 
 if (element[0].files) {
                        scope.files.length = 0; // Breakpoint not hit here
this line. i am able to execute this line. Change normally works when you select different images each time. If i understand something wrong kindly correct me